# Rails upgrade: rxml file rendered instead of haml file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, rendering, upgrade, haml

I'm upgrading an old Rails 1.x app to 2.3.10, and I'm running into a problem with rendering views. I have a controller that has two views associated with it: `index.haml` and `index.rxml`. Before the upgrade everything worked as expected. After moving to Rails 2, the same code (with no changes) has started automatically rendering the XML view at the end of the `wants.html` block, when it should be rendering the haml view. When I rename the `index.rxml` file to something else (like `foo.rxml`), it successfully finds and renders the `index.haml` file.

What changed in the view rendering logic from Rails 1 to Rails 2 that is causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't worked with Rails 1 (jumped in at Rails 2), but I guess it's because Rails 2 uses .html.erb instead of .rhtml. Same goes for .xml.erb instead of .rxml. And the same thing has happened for HAML: .haml becomes .html.haml. Don't know if this is the thing causing your problem, but it's the Rails 2 way of creating views.

**EDIT**

Also, if you want to render XML in Rails 2, you need to add the following to your Controller:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.xml { render :xml_view_name } 
end
```

Comment: Renaming the views fixed it. I used the rake task [here](http://thelucid.com/2007/05/16/rails-edge-getting-your-view-extensions-ready-for-edge/).